# property 'update' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular

I'm into a starter AngularCli project which require Gauge chart.
For this I've used the code from
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjk9sl?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

On `ng serve --open`, it shows error in the terminal as

> ERROR in src/app/gauge/gauge.component.ts(100,21): error TS2339: Property
>   'configure' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   src/app/gauge/gauge.component.ts(109,21): error TS2339: Property
>   'isRendered' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   src/app/gauge/gauge.component.ts(161,21): error TS2339: Property
>   'render' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   src/app/gauge/gauge.component.ts(173,21): error TS2339: Property
>   'update' does not exist on type '{}'.
>   src/app/gauge/gauge.component.ts(188,16): error TS2339: Property
>   'render' does not exist on type '{}'.

and the browser output like,

> Cannot GET /

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `gaugemap` is now `{}` and as you see it has nothing in it. Set the type for `gaugemap` to `any` for passing compiler

```
gaugemap: any = {}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it doesn't show the error.
But the gaugechart is not displayed on the browser

Comment: You can also make a type for it using `interface` and defined your properties

Comment: instead of `any` you can create your custom type for it. See `interfaces` in TypeScript

Comment: How can I display the Gauge chart in browser?
No error is showing in Terminal.