# expo Property does not exist on type{}

Tags: react-native, expo, geofencing

I am debugging a code I have not written, and I am new to typescript.
I am imspired by [expo official document code](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/location/#locationstartlocationupdatesasynctaskname-options),
I am getting a TS2339 error

> Property 'eventType' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> Property 'region' does not exist on type '{}'.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { GeofencingEventType } from 'expo-location';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';


TaskManager.defineTask('YOUR_TASK_NAME', ({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (eventType === GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("You've entered region:", region);
  } else if (eventType === GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
    console.log("You've left region:", region);
  }
})




const LATITUDE = 43.653225;
const LONGITUDE = -79.383186;
export default function App() {
  const [coordinates] = useState([
    {
      latitude: 43.7860253, longitude: -79.2936040,
      //home
    },
    {
      latitude: 43.7851554, longitude: -79.2934172,
      //library
    },
    {
      latitude: 43.7843101, longitude: -79.2913043,
      //walmart
    },
    {
      latitude: 43.7862644, longitude: -79.2913092,
      //158 bonis avenue
    },
    {
      latitude: 43.7860253, longitude: -79.2936040,
      //home,coordinates should be a circle if want to be the starting point
    },
  ]); 

  const origin = {latitude: 43.791680, longitude: -79.312770};
  const destination = {latitude: 43.785230, longitude: -79.293420};
  const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'AIzaSyBpAexI1D_HPIrR9xz_RqAAKDNlYKmW0Q8';


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      console.log("success")
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      console.log(status);
      if (status === 'granted') {
        await Location.startGeofencingAsync("YOUR_TASK_NAME", [
          {
            latitude: 43.7860253, longitude: -79.2936040,"radius": 20,
            //home
          },]);
      }
    })
      
  }, []);

 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.maps}
        provider={"google"}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: coordinates[0].latitude,
          longitude: coordinates[0].longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
        }}>
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={coordinates[0]}
          destination={coordinates[coordinates.length-1]}
          mode="WALKING"
          waypoints={ (coordinates.length > 2) ? coordinates.slice(1, -1): undefined}
          apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY} // insert your API Key here
          strokeWidth={4}
          strokeColor="#111111"
        />
        <Marker coordinate={coordinates[0]} />
        <Marker coordinate={coordinates[1]} />
        <Marker coordinate={coordinates[2]} />
        <Marker coordinate={coordinates[3]} />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  maps: {
    width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
  },
})
```

i try many way to solve it as following but failed:

- [Typescript property does not exist on type {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467069/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type)
- [Property 'xxx' does not exist on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377151/property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type)
- [property 'update' does not exist on type '{}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051108/property-update-does-not-exist-on-type)

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

what happens is that "*data*" has the type {} (empty object)

so, what typescript thinks you are doing is something like this

```js
const data: {} = {};
console.log(data.region); // Property 'region' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

this is basically a library error in defining the types.

**Solution:**
what we are going to do is to change the type to the right ones:

```js
import { TaskManagerError } from "expo-task-manager";

type DefineTaskProps = {
   error: null | TaskManagerError,
   data: { 
      eventType: string;
      region: string;
   }
}
TaskManager.defineTask('TASK_NAME', (
   { data: { eventType, region }, error } as unknow as DefineTaskProps,
   ...
);
```

Comment: hi,`({ data: { eventType, region }, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (eventType === GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("You've entered region:", region);
  } else if (eventType === GeofencingEventType.Exit) {
    console.log("You've left region:", region);
  }
}`,how to embed the type assersion to arrow function?can you clarify?